# My divs are out of order and aligned at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

Here's the code in the body of my HTML:

```
<div id="mtx_bckgd">
    <p id="mtx_txt"></p>
</div>
<div class="outerdiv" id="headerbox">
    <div id="uwlogo">
        <img src="uwlogo.png" height="50px">
    </div>
    <div id="JaminWEB">
        <h1>JaminWEB</h1>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="outerdiv" id="navbar">
    <a href="runningCalculator.html"><input type="button" class="navbutton" value="Running Calculator"/></a>
    <input type="button" class="navbutton"/>
    <input type="button" class="navbutton"/>
</div>
<div class="outerdiv" id="footer">
    <p>Last modified: March 21st, 2014</p>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
#mtx_bckgd
{
    font-family: "Courier New";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #39275b, #FFF);
}

#headerbox
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
}

#navbar
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
}

#footer
{   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

The headerbox and navbar are supposed to be aligned at the top in their respective orders. The footer is supposed to be aligned at the bottom. What's going on that is making my footer **ABOVE** the other two, and everything aligned at the bottom?

Comment: I've done a JSFiddle here, and can't see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/LL889/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

```
height: 100%;
```

from the #mtx_bckgd element

Also, nothing to do with the problem, but change

```
<img src="uwlogo.png" height="50px">
```

to

```
<img src="uwlogo.png" height="50px" />
```

As your image tag isn't closed

Answer (score 0):

The mtx_bckgd is occupying 100% width and 100% height (so all your screen). The footer is absolute at the bottom, so it's over the mtx_bckgd and at the bottom of your screen. Finally, the two other div tags, are at the bottom cuz again the mtx_bckgd is occupying all the screen and they have to be after it.

What layout do you want to achieve ?